# How do I combine an IF formula with a dropdown in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dropdown, excel-indirect

Here's what I am trying to achieve. If a student earns a grade 1* or a 1, they do not get a key. If they earn a grade 2 or 3, the teacher then chooses from these keys: 
A - Attendance
B - Behaviour
C - Classwork
L - Lateness
O - Organization
H - Homework.

What I want to do is, create a  drop-down with the options 1*,1,2,3. If the teacher selects 2 or 3, it will then provide another drop down with the keys(A,B,C,H,L,O). I know this can somehow be done using dependent drop downs but somehow this doesn't work for me.

**What I have done so far:**
I have a column labelled "Grades" with a dropdown menu listing 1*,1,2,3.
I then created another column with the label "key" and used the data validation method and the formula "=INDIRECT".

What happens then is that the "key" column doesnt give me a dropdown menu. It's just a blank cell.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did something similar using a choose() to select between the choices, perhaps you can try that.

Comment: @SolarMike How does that work? We are dealing with a noob here :(

Comment: Have you tead the helpfile entry for choose()? Have you tested it? That’s the best way to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround,

use a table, I use the name "tbl_gradechoose" for it.
For every grade a column.
Use the Datavalidation, choose List and as source the formula

```
=INDIRECT("tbl_gradechoose[" & A1 &"]")
```

Here shown in englisch Excel Version:
[image]

Here shown in the German Version in Excle:
[image]

Comment: I tried this and it returns the message: "The Source currently evaluates to an error. Do you want to continue?" What is it I am doing wrong? Could you explain the ([" & A1 &"]") part to me please? What is happening there? Thanks :)

Comment: Please check the Formula, normaly this error Pops up if there is a typing error within the INDIRECT() Formula. Check  especially  the tablename and the quotation marks

Comment: I edited the answer with a picture of the english Excel Version